# how to import a radian file from python, and how must I print out a large number

Tags: python

```
# Definition of radius
r = 192500

# Import radians function of math package

from math import radians

# Travel distance of Moon over 12 degrees. Store in dist.

dist=int(r*(math.radians(12)))

# Print out dist

print(dist)
```

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> r = 192500
> from math import radians
> dist=int(r*(math.radians(12)))
> ```

If you `from math import radians`, then you have to write just `radians` rather than `math.radians`.
If you `import math`, then you have to write `math.radians`.